# Automapper - Assign Ranking in the Destination object

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-5

I am having the below source and destination objects:

```
public class Source
{       
    public string Value1{ get; set; }

}

public class Destination 
{
    public string Value1{ get; set; }
    public int Ranking { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to map the collection object of Source to Collection object of destination. My source collection is like this:

```
var source = new List<Source>();
source.Add(new Source(){ Value1= "test1" });
source.Add(new Source(){ Value1= "test2" });
```

How can I write the mapper if the Ranking attribute in the destination object should correspond to the item index in the source collection?

I.e. after mapping the destination ranking for the `Source` with `Value1 = "test1"` will be `1` and the next one will be `2`.

Comment: Why do you want to do something like that? It's a one big code smell. Instead of looking AutoMapper solutions, try to make this code simpler

Comment: I wanted to know there is anything which the Automapper provides out of the box. I did not want to iterate through the list and map the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it a few ways but if you want your converter unit testable I would suggest using a class that inherits from `ITyperConverter<TSource, TDestination>`.

Convert Class:

```
public class SourceToDestinationConverter : ITypeConverter<Source, Destination>
{
    private int currentRank;
    public SourceToDestinationConverter(int rank)
    {
        currentRank = rank;
    }

    public Destination Convert(Source source, Destination destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        destination = new Destination
        {
            Value1 = source.Value1,
            Ranking = currentRank
        };
        return destination;
    }
}
```

Setting your class to the Mapper Configuration:

```
Mapper.Initialize(config =>
{
        config.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ConvertUsing<SourceToDestinationConverter>();
});
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Calling the method:

```
var sources = new List<Source>{
    new Source() { Value1 = "test1" },
    new Source() { Value1 = "test2" }
};

var destinationsRanked = sources.Select(s => Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(s, options => options.ConstructServicesUsing(
        type => new SourceToDestinationConverter((source.IndexOf(s) + 1))
)));
```

The result ends up being.

```
Value1 | Ranking
test1  | 1
test2  | 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use before and after map actions (see  [the docs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Before-and-after-map-actions)):

```
var source = new List<Source>();
source.Add(new Source() { Value1 = "test1" });
source.Add(new Source() { Value1 = "test2" });

Mapper.Initialize(config =>
{
    config.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
});

var destinations = source.Select(x => Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(x, opt => {
    opt.AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Ranking = source.IndexOf(x) + 1);
}));
```